# Unit Testing socket.io in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, socket.io, jasmine

I am trying to unit test an angular service in my application, which creates socket.io client. My service looks something like this:

```
export class SocketService {
  private name: string;
  private host: string = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":3000";
  socket: io.Socket;

  constructor() { }

  subscribeEvent(name: string): Observable<IJobResp> {
    this.setup(name);
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket.on('job', val => observer.next(val))
    })
  }

  private setup(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
    let socketUrl = this.host + "/" + this.name;
    this.socket = io.connect(socketUrl);
  }
}
```

So to write my test, I am using the mock-socket library to set up a mock socket.io server. Here is what the test looks like:

```
describe('SocketService', () => {
  let socket;

  const mockServer = new Server('http://localhost:3000/');
  mockServer.on('connection', server => {
    mockServer.emit('job', 'test message 1');
  });

  (window as any).io = SocketIO;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [JobService]
    });
  });

  it('should xyz, inject([JobService], fakeAsync((service: JobService) => {
    service.subscribeEvent('/').subscribe(val => {
      expect(val).toEqual('test message 1');
    })
  })));
});
```

However, that test throws the error:

> Error: Cannot make XHRs from within a fake async test.

If I don't have the `fakeAsync`, then the test passes before the assertion in the `subscribe()` is processed.

How do I get around this?

## Update:

Another approach I have tried is to use `async` e.g.

```
  it('should subscribe to dwnTime events', async(inject([JobService], (service: JobService) => {
    service.subscribeEvent('line/602').subscribe(val => {
      expect(val).toEqual('test 2');
    })
  })));
```

Then I get:

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

This looks like a timing issue, but I still am not sure why?

Comment: It would be easier to test your service if it did not refer to globals. Why not inject `io` or at least import it so that something can replace it?

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach is the right one as the mock server is a real one, therefore you need to increase the timeout by setting

`jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;` (the value is to be adjusted)

anywhere inside the describe function.

[Here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) you can find a full example.

Comment: Link is broken.