# unit-testing Angular 5 with socket.io mockup

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, socket.io, jasmine

Im trying to unit-test a service which has [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) imported by using [mock-socket](https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket#readme). I looked at similar problem such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656279/unit-testing-socket-io-in-angular?answertab=active#tab-top) one and I'm not being able to get it to work with following.

```
import { TestBed, inject, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SocketIO, Server } from 'mock-socket';
import { BackendService } from './backend.service';

  describe('BackendService', () => {

  /* setup for mock-socket in order to test socket.io */
  const SERVER_URL = window.location.host;
  const mockServer = new Server(SERVER_URL);

  // setting up server mock
  mockServer.on('connection', socket => {
    mockServer.emit('server-message', 'test message 1');
  });

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ ],
        providers: [ BackendService ]
    });

    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000;

  });

  it('tests simple connection and messaging works with mock-socket setup', async(inject([BackendService], (service: BackendService) => {

  (window as any).io = SocketIO;  

  // setting up client
  service.socket = io(window.location.host);

  setTimeout(() => {
      service.socket.on('connect', (message) => {
          expect(message).toEqual('test message 1');
          mockServer.stop();
      });  
  }, 100);

  })));

});
```

Anyone that has come around this?

I've created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-unit-test-socketio?embed=1&file=src/app/test-view-socketIO/backend.service.spec.ts&view=preview) to recreate the scenario if it makes things easier to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing to following lines:

```
  it('tests simple connection and messaging with mock-socket setup', async(done: DoneFn) => {

  (window as any).io = SocketIO;  

  // setting up client
  backendService.socket = io(window.location.host);


  backendService.socket.on('server-message', (message) => {
    console.log(message)
    expect(message.message).toEqual('test message 1');
    mockServer.stop();
    done();
  });  

  });

});
```

The issue itself was due to that you need to inform Jasmine when the [asynchronous](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) operation is done.

This is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-unit-test-socketio-working) to see the test working.